# I can't delete my status

Tags: laravel

My error is:

> FatalErrorException in 077cf636f32dba5a90c4b83021f7bfea049823d7.php line 0: Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception

My route:

```
Route::get('/delete-status/{status_id}', [
    'uses' => 'Classroom@getDeleteStatus',
    'as' => 'Status.delete',
    'middleware' => 'auth'
]);
```

My controller:

```
public function getDeleteStatus($status_id)
{
    $status = Status::where('id', $status_id)->first();

    $status->delete();
    return redirect()->route('class')->with(['message' => 'Successfully deleted!']);
}
```

My view:

```
<div style="text-align: right">
    <a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a> ||
    <a href="{{ route('status.delete', ['status_id' => $status->id]) }}">Delete</a>
</div>
```

What should I do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

yes i fixed my problem...

my view should be

```
<div style="text-align: right">
<a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a> ||
<a href="{{ route('Status.delete', ['status_id' => $status->id]) }}">Delete</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your route should be delete. Route::delete

```
Route::delete('/delete-status/{status_id}', [
'uses' => 'Classroom@getDeleteStatus',
'as' => 'Status.delete',
'middleware' => 'auth']);
```

What I did way back then is a Resource controller, but you can use Route::delete
you can check more about resource controller here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers

in your view:

```
<form action="action('Classroom@getDeleteStatus', {{$status_id}})" method="POST">
     <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
     {{ csrf_field() }}
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger pull-left"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
</form>
```

then in your controller

```
public function getDeleteStatus($status_id)
{
    $status = Status::where('id', $status_id)->first();


    $status->delete();
    return redirect()->route('class')->with(['message' => 'Successfully deleted!']);
}
```